# PL/SQL Variable parameters in procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I need to create a procedure that allows a user to input information for an order (which is below), but also for *n* number of suborders (where 2 ≤ *n* ≥ 10). How would I be able to incorporate this into the procedure I already have? I'm using SQLPlus. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VIEW_ORDER(ORDERS IN CHAR)
AS

CURSOR ORDER_CUR IS

  SELECT * FROM SUBORDERS
  WHERE ORDER_NO = ORDERS;

BEGIN
    FOR O_REC IN ORDER_CUR
    LOOP

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Code: ' || O_REC.prod_id 
  || ' Order: ' || O_REC.order_no 
  || ' Suborder: ' || O_REC.suborder_no
  || ' Quantity: ' || O_REC.quantity);
  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product number does not exist'); 
WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Operation failed  ' || 'SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE); 
ROLLBACK;
END; 
/
```

Comment: Write an anoymous block and check the validation of n in that and then call your exisitng procedure in that.

Comment: You can not do a double comparison in a where. you must do it using the `and`. Like this: `where 2<=n and n<=10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for an input sqlplus command `ACCEPT` and make another loop to take n suborders.

If I didn't missunderstood your question it would be something like this:

```
-- You have to create the input outside the procedure
accept n char prompt 'Please enter n suborders: '

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VIEW_ORDER(ORDERS IN CHAR)
AS

  CURSOR ORDER_CUR IS

    SELECT * FROM SUBORDERS
    WHERE ORDER_NO = ORDERS;

BEGIN
  FOR O_REC IN ORDER_CUR
  LOOP

    -- Here we check if n<=2
    IF n>=2 THEN

      -- here if n<=10
      WHILE n<=10
      LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Code: ' || O_REC.prod_id 
        || ' Order: ' || O_REC.order_no 
        || ' Suborder: ' || O_REC.suborder_no
        || ' Quantity: ' || O_REC.quantity);
      END LOOP;
     END IF;
    END LOOP;


EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product number does not exist'); 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Operation failed  ' || 'SQLCODE: ' 
  || 
  SQLCODE); 
  ROLLBACK;
END; 
/
```